# export default class Page Or export default App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know what is difference between example one and example two in Reactjs.

**Example one**

```
 export default class Page extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
            debugger
            super(props);
        }
    }
```

**Example Two**

```
class Page extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
        debugger
        super(props);
    }
}
export default Page;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost no difference between those two examples.
They are just simply differently written.

If you modify this examples you will see bigger difference betwean them (but still they work the same)

**Example one**

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        debugger;
        super(props);
    }
}
```

**Example Two**

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        debugger;
        super(props);
    }
}

export default Page;
```

Now you can see that in **Example one** name of class is redundant - it's shorthand.